# How can I filter a Pandas GroupBy object and obtain a GroupBy object back?

Tags: python, pandas

When performing filter on the result of a Pandas groupby operation, it returns a dataframe.  But supposing that I want to perform further group computations, I have to call groupby again, which seems sort of round about.  Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

To illustrate what I'm talking about:

We shamelessly steal a toy dataframe from the Pandas docs, and group:

```
>>> dff = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(8), 'B': list('aabbbbcc')})
>>> grouped = dff.groupby('B')
>>> type(grouped)
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

This returns a groupby object over which we can iterate, perform group-wise operations, etc.  But if we filter:

```
>>> filtered = grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
>>> type(filtered)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

We get back a dataframe.  Is there a nice idiomatic way of obtaining the filtered groups back, instead of just the original rows which belonged to the filtered groups?

Comment: Please give an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: I think this is a good queston, in SQL you can combine the groupby by and filter as `SELECT user, SUM(likes) GROUP BY user HAVING sum(likes) > 10` whereas in pandas you would have to do `df.groupby('user').filter(lambda x: len(x)>10).groupby('user').likes.sum()`; maybe the answer would be to include a filter keyword in `groupby` or an `as_index` keyword in `filter`?

Comment: @BrenBarn: example added.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine a filter and an aggregate, the best way I can think of would be to combine your filter and aggregate using a ternary `if` inside `apply`, returning `None` for filtered groups, and then `dropna` to remove these rows from your final result:

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sum() if len(x) > 2 else None).dropna()
```

If you're wanting to iterate through the groups, say to join them back together, you could use a generator comprehension

```
pd.concat(g for i,g in grouped if len(g)>2)
```

Ultimately I think it would be better if `groupby.filter` had an option to return a groupby object.

Comment: He wants the actual groups back, not their sum.