# How to preserve Pandas.GroupBy object after filter operation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I wish to conduct operations on groups in my data frame but only upon filtered groups. It seems for me to do so I have to groupby, then [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/groupby.html#filtration), and then groupby again, and finally conduct my operation. Is there some means to bypass the second grouping operation? Seems wasteful if I actually want to retain the context of being a GroupBy object.

```
df2 = df1.groupby('ColumnX').filter( lambda x: len(x) >= 2 ).groupby('ColumnX').mean()
```

Is there a way to conduct a group filter whose return value is not a dataframe but a GroupBy object?

Here's some toy data to demonstrate with...

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({ 'ColumnX' : ['a', 'a', 'a' , 'b' , 'b' , 'c' ] , 'ColumnY' : [ 1 , 2  ,  3  ,  1  , 2  ,  99 ] })
>>> df
  ColumnX  ColumnY
0       a        1
1       a        2
2       a        3
3       b        1
4       b        2
5       c       99
>>> df.groupby('ColumnX')
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000000005974438>
>>> df.groupby('ColumnX').filter( lambda x : len(x) >=2 )
  ColumnX  ColumnY
0       a        1
1       a        2
2       a        3
3       b        1
4       b        2
>>> df.groupby('ColumnX').filter( lambda x : len(x) >=2 ).groupby('ColumnX')
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000000033A1588>
>>> df.groupby('ColumnX').filter( lambda x : len(x) >=2 ).groupby('ColumnX').mean()
         ColumnY
ColumnX
a            2.0
b            1.5
>>>
```

Comment: I really think you just have to call `groupby` again

Comment: @PaulH that's what I'm thinking because of the design of filter's return value. I guess there may be a bit of overhead involved, I'm not sure the internals of groubby object with respect to data frames, maybe it's not such a high penalty to pay.

Comment: You version is pretty fast - i tested another one (using `df.groupby('ColumnX').agg({'ColumnY': ['mean', 'size']})`) - and it was almost two times slower than yours

Comment: this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832475/how-can-i-filter-a-pandas-groupby-object-and-obtain-a-groupby-object-back/35833691#35833691 (which doesn't have an accepted answer though)

Comment: aha you're right, I was looking for something like that but didn't look hard enough it would seem. I think your comment is key, "_Ultimately I think it would be better if groupby.filter had an option to return a groupby object_", the problem is in the design of the return value. Maybe they could implement a filtergroups method or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter a Pandas GroupBy object and obtain a GroupBy object back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832475/how-can-i-filter-a-pandas-groupby-object-and-obtain-a-groupby-object-back)